# Function to compare two iterators

Tags: rust

I'd like to have a function to compare two iterators. To complicate things, it also happens that the iterators' items are **references**, not owned values.

My attempt at what its signature may look like:

```rust
fn diff<T: PartialEq<T>>(
    new: impl IntoIterator<Item = &T>, 
    existing: impl IntoIterator<Item = &T>
) -> (HashSet<T>, HashSet<T>) {
    ...
}
```

The function should compare two iterators and return a "diff" tuple, where the first element is the items which must be *added* and the second element the items which must be *removed*, to make `existing` become `new`.

For example:

```rust
let x = vec!(&1,&2,&3);
let y = vec!(&1,&4);
assert_eq!(
    diff(&y[..], &x[..]), 
    (
        HashSet::from_iter(vec!(4).iter().cloned()), 
        HashSet::from_iter(vec!(2, 3).iter().cloned())
    )
);
```

Whatever I try runs into various compiler complaints about moving values which don't implement `Copy` etc. My initial approach used the [partition_map](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.partition_map) from the `itertools` crate.

Here's the start of my implementation and the error it produces:

```rust
    let (add, common): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) =
        new.into_iter().partition_map(|t| match existing.into_iter().contains(t) {
            false => Either::Left(t),
            true => Either::Right(t),
        });
```

> cannot move out of `existing`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
> move occurs because `existing` has type `impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a T>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

Edit: In fact, can return **owned** values, by cloning them.

Comment: `existing.into_iter()` consumes `existing` and thus can only be called once unless `existing` is copied (or cloned, etc.)

Comment: Ah I see. Seems a shame to have to clone before any comparisons. I was hoping cloning only the items required in the result would work.

Comment: No, you absolutely do not need to clone the elements of the vector every time - that would be a performance disaster for large `T`!  What you need to do is create a new iterator over the vector each time, by either cloning an existing iterator or calling `.iter()` on the vector.  The interface of `diff` might need to change though.

Comment: Hmm trouble is I don't have a `Vec` with an `iter` method, just some type which implements `IntoIterator`...

Comment: Since you are not also tracking the position at which elements should be added/removed, one presumes that position is not meaningful; but then, unless the iterators are guaranteed to be sorted, when you encounter a mismatch between them how do you know whether the missing element has/will be found elsewhere?  Will you subsequently deduplicate between the resulting addition/removal sets?  Feels to me as though this problem would generally be better solved using a set type rather than iterators.

Comment: @eggyal a fair comment. Set types require `Hash` but unfortunately for me the elements of the iterators are not `Hash`. I'm not sure what other approach I can take.

Comment: `BTreeSet` "only" requires `Ord`, not `Hash`—but perhaps you can newtype the elements as a workaround?  Hard to say what's best without wider context.

Comment: Well let's ask differently .. what **is** known about them? Should they be compared purely by their reference address? Or by `Eq`? By `Ord`? If `Eq` is the only thing we got, this will become a `O(N^2)` operation.

Comment: It looks to me like you need some time still thinking about your requirements, since they're crucial to giving a good answer this question as is lacks details.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Consider `diff([1, 2], [2, 1])`. Should the answer be `({1}, {2})`, or `({2}, {1})`, or `({}, {})`? What about duplicates? Why are the inputs iterators, which can have repeats and for which the order of elements matters, but the output is a pair of sets?